# Logstash filter pattern for Audit logs?

Tags: linux, logstash, logstash-grok, elk, audit-logging

I am collecting all levels of logs including AuditD logs from my VM's using Syslog and keeping in the centralized location which is Syslog server. Then I am pushing all my VM's logs to ELK stack using filebeat. While pushing to the logstash. I want to separate following details from my auditD logs

```
1) User Name
2) What command he executed
```

I Used the following pattern to separate the same but I am not able to get the username as a string since **AUID** taking as an integer.

Used Pattern

`type=%{WORD:audit_type} msg=audit\(%{NUMBER:audit_epoch}:%{NUMBER:audit_counter}\): arch=%{NOTSPACE} syscall=%{NUMBER:syscall_number} success=(?<syscall_sucess>(yes|no)) exit=%{NUMBER:syscall_exit_code} %{GREEDYDATA:syscall_arguments} items=%{NUMBER:syscall_path_records} ppid=%{NUMBER:syscall_parent_pid} pid=%{NUMBER:syscall_pid} auid=%{NUMBER:uid_audit} uid=%{NUMBER:running_uid} gid=%{NUMBER:group_id} euid=%{NUMBER:uid_effective} suid=%{NUMBER:uid_set} fsuid=%{NUMBER:uid_fs} egid=%{NUMBER:gid_effective} sgid=%{NUMBER:gid_set} fsgid=%{NUMBER:gid_fs} tty=%{NOTSPACE:tty} ses=%{NUMBER:session_id} comm=\"%{GREEDYDATA:command}\" exe=\"%{GREEDYDATA:exec_file}\" key=\"%{GREEDYDATA:audit_rule}\" SYSCALL=\"%{GREEDYDATA:syscall}\" AUID=\"%{GREEDYDATA:user}\"`

My example input

`type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1582540425.222:375): arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=yes exit=0 a0=55ea2c3d1f90 a1=55ea2c2e2c20 a2=55ea2c41f570 a3=0 items=2 ppid=16081 pid=16249 auid=1578986719 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=1 comm="sudo" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" key="rootact"#035ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=execve AUID="giri" UID="root" GID="root" EUID="root" SUID="root" FSUID="root" EGID="root" SGID="root" FSGID="root"`

from the above example, I can able to get the auid as 1578986719 but not as giri which is AUID.

Kindly help me to get the AUID as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this pattern helps to get AUID as string

```
type=%{WORD:audit_type} msg=audit\(%{NUMBER:audit_epoch}:%{NUMBER:audit_counter}\): arch=%{NOTSPACE} syscall=%{NUMBER:syscall_number} success=(?<syscall_sucess>(yes|no)) exit=%{NUMBER:syscall_exit_code} %{GREEDYDATA:syscall_arguments} items=%{NUMBER:syscall_path_records} ppid=%{NUMBER:syscall_parent_pid} pid=%{NUMBER:syscall_pid} auid=%{NUMBER:uid_audit} uid=%{NUMBER:running_uid} gid=%{NUMBER:group_id} euid=%{NUMBER:uid_effective} suid=%{NUMBER:uid_set} fsuid=%{NUMBER:uid_fs} egid=%{NUMBER:gid_effective} sgid=%{NUMBER:gid_set} fsgid=%{NUMBER:gid_fs} tty=%{NOTSPACE:tty} ses=%{NUMBER:session_id} comm=\"%{GREEDYDATA:command}\" exe=\"%{GREEDYDATA:exec_file}\" key=\"%{GREEDYDATA:audit_rule}\"%{GREEDYDATA} SYSCALL=%{GREEDYDATA:syscall} AUID=\"%{GREEDYDATA:user}\" UID
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're just interested in the user name and AUID, you can use this pattern:

```
(?=.*auid=%{NUMBER:uid_audit})(?=.*AUID=\"%{DATA:user}\")
```

Which doesn't rely on the log format staying the same.